# "Extra \else" with pdflatex, CJKutf8, and hyperref packages, and kanji inside \nolinkurl

Tags: errors, pdftex, hyperref, cjk

I am trying to typeset a document that contains hypothetical IDN domain names containing kanji and/or kana.  I'm getting an `! Extra \else` error coming from the guts of the CJK package's macro definitions of Unicode characters.  I've managed to cut it down to this test case:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{CJKutf8}
\begin{document}
\begin{CJK}{UTF8}{song}
\nolinkurl{日本.example}
\end{CJK}
\end{document}
```

⟶

```
! Extra \else.
\CJK@XXX ...}\expandafter \CJK@ignorespaces \else
                                                  \csname u8:\string #1\stri...
l.7 \nolinkurl{日本.example}

?
```

This is with TeX Live 2020 (pdfTeX 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.21, LaTeX2e <2020-02-02> patch level 5, CJK 2015/04/18 4.1.4).

The error goes away if I `\usepackage{CJK}` instead of `\usepackage{CJKutf8}` but then the rendering is wrong:

> [image: <code>{\global\let}{\global\let}.example</code>]

Can anyone suggest a workaround?

Note: because the document might go on the arXiv eventually, lualatex is not an option, I'm stuck with classic pdflatex.

Comment: why are you using \nolinkurl instead of e.g. \texttt{...}?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer If I use \texttt then it won't break the line in the middle of one of these. It's a two column paper so I really need that.

Comment: Insert breakpoints manually then.